# Scale control (bottom left) in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api (along with styles) to display poi.attraction of a particular place.

I need to diplay scale control to check the distance. I used the following code and got a **smaller scale** which is at the **bottom right**.

All i need is a larger scale on the **left bottom side.**

```
var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    zoom:10,
    panControl:true,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:true,
    scaleControl:true,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: styles
};
```

Comment: What is in your `styles`? Via `scaleControlOptions` (which is an object) you can specifiy the position and the style. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ScaleControlOptions)

Answer (score 1):

From version 3.14 on visual refresh is active. The below is from the documentation referenced.

> When google.maps.visualRefresh is true the scale control will be fixed at the BOTTOM_RIGHT.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer, but it still sucks